# how to make half of the srting in uppercase and the other half in lowercase?

Tags: javascript

I Tried to made a code that turn half of the sentence to Uppercase and the other half to Lowercase but it's not working. Need help, this is my code.

```
const fullClintStr = prompt("please enter text: ");
const strlen = fullClintStr.length;
const lowerCaseStr = fullClintStr.toLowerCase();
const upperCaseStr = fullClintStr.toUpperCase();
const MiddleSentence = (strlen/2).toFixed(0);

for (let i = 0; i < MiddleSentence; i++) {
    
    var finalSTR = upperCaseStr[i].toUpperCase(upperCaseStr[i]);
    
    
}
window.alert(finalSTR);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `slice` method to get what you want instead of looping over. Also your loop isn't working because your `finalStr` gets re-assigned the latest character.

Again there is a definitely scope to prevent **lowercasing** and **uppercasing** the whole strings and instead just do those for the `left and right substrings` and adding them both to get the `finalStr` as @Tim did.

```js
const fullClintStr = prompt("please enter text: ");
const strlen = fullClintStr.length;
const lowerCaseStr = fullClintStr.toLowerCase();
const upperCaseStr = fullClintStr.toUpperCase();
const MiddleSentence = (strlen/2).toFixed(0);
let finalSTR = lowerCaseStr.slice(0,MiddleSentence) + upperCaseStr.slice(MiddleSentence, strlen);


window.alert(finalSTR);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `substring` here:

```js
var fullClintStr = "javascript";
var strlen = fullClintStr.length;
var output = fullClintStr.substring(0, strlen/2).toLowerCase() +
             fullClintStr.substring(strlen/2).toUpperCase();
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```js
const fullClintStr = prompt("please enter text: ");

const firstHalf = fullClintStr.substring(0, fullClintStr.length / 2).toUpperCase();
const secondHalf = fullClintStr.substring((fullClintStr.length / 2), fullClintStr.length).toLowerCase();

const finalText = `${firstHalf}${secondHalf}`

console.log(finalText)
```